# How is Splash Page in Russian (IT)?

Tags: значения

How is Splash Page in Russian (IT)?

Comment: По аналогии с Splash Screen - "экран-заставка", "окно-заставка", просто "заставка" могу предложить "страница-заставка".

Comment: @Artemix spasiba

Comment: @Artemix Hotspot kak po ruski? spasiba

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Please provide some context to your translation request (i. e. how would you use this phrase in an English sentence) and demonstrate your own effort to translate it (what did you try and why don't you like the result). Thanks!